# Word 2010 Context menu disappears

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I'm having a bizarre problem with Word 2010.

When I right click for the context menu, the menu flashes up for a fraction of a second and then disappears when you would expect it to stay until dismissed.

There's nothing wrong with my mouse.

This is on Windows 7.

A google for this issue seems to place it at the doorstep of and Add-in called Babylon. I haven't got this Add-In installed. In fact, I have disabled all Add-Ins.

Any ideas? This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is putty.

If I shut down putty the context menu works correctly. If I start it back up, it misbehaves.

Annoying as I need to use both M$ apps and putty all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different mouse? Does this happen in any other applications? Have you checked for any processes using regularly high levels of cpu around the time you right-click? It's possible a signal is being sent from a different program that is interrupting the "right-click" signal you sent yourself.